questions about Quillen's Q-construction
I've been recently reading Marco Schlichtings' notes on "Higher algebraic K-theory", and in the second section of the second chapter page 172, he introduces Quillen’s Q-construction for an exact category, which I don't quite get the idea of.
He introduces the K-space, defined as the loop space of the classifying space of the Q-construction of an exact category. My question is
What would happen if we use the classifying space of the exact category instead, what would go wrong if we don't use the Q-construction?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Basically because it is not going to be what we want: the $Q$-construction is “artificially” made so that there is an isomorphism $K_0(C)\to \pi_1QC$ (which is Proposition 2.2.4 of Schlichting’s notes). Moreover, the magic is that if $C$ is the category of modules over a commutative ring $R$, then we get back $K(R)$ by Theorem 2.2.8 of Schlichting’s notes.
The bottom line is: there was an intrinsic definition of $K_0(R)$, $K_1(R)$ and $K_2(R)$ with $R$ a commutative ring, then people came up with a space $K(R)$ such $\pi_iK(R)=K_i(R)$ for $i=0,1,2$, and finally with a definition of $K(C)$ for any exact category $C$ such that if $C=\mathrm{Mod}(R)$, then $K(R)$ and $K(C)$ are homotopy equivalent.
If you only use the classifying space, there is no relation between $K_0(C)$ and $\pi_1BC$, and the latter is in general very hard to compute: in particular all the nice techniques that we usually use in algebraic $K$-theory (e.g. Theorems 2.3.2 and 2.3.3 of Schlichting’s notes) would be false.
